# Jetpack Compose how to center hint and input inside BasicTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm trying to make an editText which fills the width of the screen, and it's hint and input starts from the center of the screen.

I choose BasicTextField, since the styles of TextField and OutlinedTextFields are completely unnecessary to me.

I've tried doing this.

```
      BasicTextField(
                value = loginId,
                onValueChange = {
                    loginId = it
                },
                decorationBox = {
                     Text(text = "Input your id", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally).fillMaxWidth())
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 19.dp,
                        bottom = 4.5.dp, end = 19.dp, top = 40.dp)
                    .background(Purple200)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            )
```

This has no effect. What can I do with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply [**`TextAlign.Center`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign#Center) to your `Text`. You can use the `style` or the `textAlign` properties.
Something like:

```
Text(text = "Input your id",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center))
```

or:

```
 Text(text = "Input your id",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
```

[image]

Also to work correctly, since you are using the `decorationBox`, you must call `innerTextField` exactly once inside your `decorationBox`.
Something like:

```
 decorationBox = {  innerTextField ->
        //....
        if (loginId.isEmpty()) {
            Text("....")
        }
        innerTextField()  //<-- Add this
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Text Composable have textAlign parameter, so you can simply centre your text using this parameter :

```
Text(text = "Input your id",
     textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
)
```

[image]

Reference: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#text-alignment